# wrapfigure in moderncv

Tags: moderncv, wrapfigure, textpos

I want to add my photo in [moderncv](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv/moderncv-banking/) environment! Itemize positioning and other floats are missed up! I tried to use [\textpos](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) package but didn't work! Here is the code

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
    \vspace*{-2.3cm}
    \hspace*{-2cm}
    \centering
    \adjustbox{cframe=color1}{\includegraphics[scale=0.07]{photo}}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

and with \textpos

```
\begin{textblock}{7}(7,7)
    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{photo}
    \end{figure}
\end{textblock}
```

I get these errors: Environment \begin{figure} is undefined and textblock ended with \end{figure}

Comment: Simply use `\includegraphics` without `wrap figure ` or `figure` environments. If it is a photo, `moderncv` provides a macro. No need of this exercise.

Comment: I want to add it in a specific place next to a section I added as Personal Information

Comment: with \includegraphics I can't fix it in absolute position like [this](http://postimg.org/image/d5ucd7kwt/)

Comment: I tried that before but for a reason the photo is all white! Maybe I have to cleanup the packages I am using :D Anyway thanks!

Comment: `\begin{textblock}{7}(4,7)
        \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{photo}
\end{textblock}` works for me.

Comment: I used the original packages and use as you suggested it worked :D Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use `wrapfigure` in this context as it demands too much for it to be properly placed. On the other hand, if you want to `overlay` the photo, you can use `textpos` package but don't put your photo inside a `figure` environment as it is a float. This is how it should be done:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\begin{document}
  \begin{textblock}{7}(7,7)                   %% adjust position
        \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{photo}
\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option will be to use `tikz` with `remember picture, and`overlay` options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node at ($(current page.north) +(0,-6in)$){\includegraphics[scale=0.7]{photo}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here you can use page location hooks so that job becomes easy.

Comment: Actually textpos did the job as I said ;) I used it first time correctly without \begin{figure} but I had a package ripping off my floats! I changed myself in the cls files and used different stuff before! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're suffering from two entirely reasonable misapprehensions.

The first thing to point out is that the `{figure}` environment in fact has very little to do with graphics: `\includegraphics` may go anywhere, and a `{figure}` may contain just text.  What `{figure}` does is (a) to provide the *floating* of a figure (of whatever type) away from the point of the file where it's described, and (b) to support a `\caption` which lets you associate text and a figure number (and LoF entry) with the content, and (c) nothing else.

Secondly, the `{wrapfigure}` environment is for the *very* specific case where you want text to wrap around a figure: the figure appears in the run of text, and the text fits in around it.  That's also largely independent of what – text or graphics – is contained in the environment.

Or, put another way, the focus on 'figure' has meant that you've made this problem a little harder for yourself than it need be.  If you think of the `\includegraphics` as a big character, and work out how to place that where you want it (and @harish-kumar has a fine illustration of how to do that with `{textblock}`), you'll get to the goal faster.